# Translating all gestures from UIView to UIScrollView on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, gesture

I've have UIView over UIScrollView.

How I can translate all gestures from UIView to UIScrollView:

- scroll (swipe)
- zoom
- dragging

Before I used touchesMoved, touchesBegan and touchesEnded methods to translate points on UIScrollView, but I can't get same effects like:

- zooming with reverting to minimum and maximum zoom if zoom value is out minimum and maximum range
- swipe scrolling
- other

Is there solution to my problem?

Comment: UIScrollView support all these gestures. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Yes, but over UIScrollView I have UIView, and all UIScrollView gestures are blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found:

```
weak var receiver: UIView!

override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

    if (self.pointInside(point, withEvent: event)) {
        return self.receiver;
    }
    return nil
}
```

---

```
touchView.receiver = scrollView
```